# How can I update my phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

How can I update my phpMyAdmin?

My current version of phpMyAdmin is 3.5.8.2.

I have downloaded the newest file for phpMyAdmin.

How can I install it?

Comment: It would help if you described how your current phpMyAdmin has been installed. Host providers and Linux distros have different ways of installing and upgrading.

Comment: Please contact the vendor for your support options. - http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/support.php

Answer (score 1):

There should be a file called INSTALL or README in the archive you downloaded. Follow those instructions.

There's also the phpMyAdmin website with a lot of instructions on that: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html - try the Quick Install instructions if you're confused by the length of it.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/webhosting/mysql/mysql-23.html):-

- Visit your MySQL administration page by clicking the "MySQL " link on
  the Create & Update or Index tabs of your Web Hosting Control

  Panel.

[image]

- On the upper-left side of the page, under "Database Setup," click
  the"Install/upgrade admin tool" link.

[image]

- Review the phpMyAdmin General Public License and click the I Agree to
  These Terms button for Installing/Upgrading phpMyAdmin.

[image]

- Locate the directory in which you originally installed phpMyAdmin and
  click the corresponding "Install phpMyAdmin Upgrade" link.
  Installation will begin automatically.

[image]

- On the following page, you'll receive confirmation of the upgrade
  with a link to your phpMyAdmin home page.

[image]